# Setting a default value for a search field in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

in the controller:

```
Order.search_one(year)

 private 
    def year
      year = params[:dyear]
      year = Time.now.year.to_s unless year
      year.gsub(/\D/,'') 
    end
```

in the form:

text_field_tag :dyear,params[:dyear]

in the model:

```
 def self.search_one(dyear)
    where("YEAR(needby) = #{dyear}").group("DATE_FORMAT(needby, '%m/%Y')").count(:needby)
  end
```

so everything works fine if you enter a year into the form search box and on initial page load.  It pulls up the current year on initial page load and gives the proper errors for any other year (I only have data for 2015 in the system, so other years are not expected to populate).  However, if you hit enter on the search field without entering a year it passes a blank value instead of setting it to Time.now.year.to_s.

any ideas on why it is passing an empty value to the model instead of the current year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `params[:dyear]` is probably `''`, which, in a conditional, is basically this:

```
string = ''    
if string
  puts "true?"
else
  puts "false"
end
#=> "true?"
```

So, you should use `params[:dyear].present?`, or:

```
year = params[:dyear]
year = Time.now.year.to_s unless year.present?
```

Comment: yep, that did the trick .present?; thanks.  I didn't even think about the fact that it was probably ' '.  I have to wait 3 minutes to accept answer.